# Default value for blank fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Appreciate if you could help.
I had populated the data from a form into a dialog box when users click on the 'submit'. However, I would like to populate and change the default value to "NIL" for empty fields. The following is my codes for populating the data:

```
jQuery('#lblCustNameBs').html(jQuery('#custNameBs').val())
jQuery('#lblembossingNameBs').html(jQuery('#embossingNameBs').val())
jQuery('#lblCustMobileBs').html(jQuery('#custMobileBs').val())
```

The code for the table are as follow:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 200px !important;">
        Salutation :
    </td>
    <td id ='lblTitleBs' />
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 200px !important;">
        Customer Name :
    </td>
    <td id ='lblCustNameBs' />
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 200px !important;">
        Embossing Name :
    </td>
    <td id ='lblembossingNameBs' />
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `jQuery('#lblCustNameBs').html(jQuery('#custNameBs').val() || 'NIL')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `||` operator to coalesce a null/undefined value to whatever you require.

Also note tat `td` cells are not self closing so you should use `<td></td>` instead of `<td />`. The use of both inline styles and `!important` should ideally be avoided too.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#lblCustNameBs').html($('#custNameBs').val() || 'NIL');
  $('#lblembossingNameBs').html($('#embossingNameBs').val() || 'NIL');
  $('#lblCustMobileBs').html($('#custMobileBs').val() || 'NIL');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 200px !important;">
      Salutation :
    </td>
    <td id="lblTitleBs"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 200px !important;">
      Customer Name :
    </td>
    <td id="lblCustNameBs"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 200px !important;">
      Embossing Name :
    </td>
    <td id="lblembossingNameBs"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks both for your help. Much appreciated